# javafx 8 WebEngine: getting console.log from javascript not working

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get the console output from JavaScript and print it to the Java console.

This is my code:

```
 WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

        engine.getLoadWorker()
                .stateProperty()
                .addListener(
                        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                            JSObject window = (JSObject) engine
                                    .executeScript("window");
                            JSListener bridge = new JSListener();
                            window.setMember("java", bridge);
                            engine.executeScript("console.log = function(message)\n"
                                    + "{\n" + "    java.log(message);\n" + "};");
                        });


public class JSListener {

    public void log(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

However, nothing is displayed when I write a console.log in the script-tag of my webpage.